# Formatting of a GET request

Tags: python, http, networking, get, carriage-return

I'm sending data in a TCP client in python and the tutorial I'm following is telling me to send this:

`"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n"`

I've tried looking up information about the formatting here and I'm confused about what the GET is actually requesting or what data would be sent back by this request, and also what is the purpose of the carriage returns and newlines?

Comment: The answer is in the HTTP specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want to write low-level HTTP GET in Python then you can create a TCP Socket and write the GET command optionally with header parameters then read the response.

The HTTP request starts with a Request-line (e.g. GET / HTTP/1.1 with a terminating CRLF or "\r\n"). The request line is followed by zero or more headers each ending with a CRLF. A final CRLF sequence marks the end of the request line and header part of the HTTP request followed by an optional message body. The request structure is defined in section 5 of the [HTTP 1.1 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-5)

```python
import socket

# host and port map to URL http://localhost:8000/
host = "localhost"
port = 8000

try:
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect((host, port))
    sock.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n".encode())
    # keep reading from socket until no more data in response
    while True:
        response = sock.recv(8096)
        if len(response) == 0:
            break
        print(response)
except Exception as ex:
    print("I/O Error:", ex)
```

The first line of the HTTP response is the status line including status code terminated with \r\n and followed by response headers.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Content-type: text/plain\r\n
Content-length: 14\r\n
\r\n
This is a test
```

You need to parse the status line and headers to determine how to decode the message body of the HTTP response.

Details of the HTTP response are in section 6 of the [HTTP 1.1 Spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-6).

Alternatively, the [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module implements the HTTP spec in a simple API.

Example to make a HTTP GET using requests API.

```python
import requests
    
url = 'http://localhost:8000/'
response = requests.get(url)
print("Status code:", response.status_code)
print("Content:", response.text)
```

Comment: All good, except that the current HTTP specs are RFC 7230 & friends.

Comment: Ack. 7230 & friends can be overwhelming for the beginner. The older versions are typically easier to understand the basics, [HTTP 1.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1945) even simpler to grasp the basic concepts but some of the details are outdated.